# cmake with antlr4 for C++ is not compiling the grammar, and also errors when I create a separate directory for generated code

Tags: c++, cmake, antlr4

I tried to copy an [antlr4 demo for C++](https://tomassetti.me/getting-started-antlr-cpp/) and build a grammar.

There is a lot of complexity in cmake that I don't understand. The demo pulls in code and builds it, but still requires that the tool directory be manually set up with an antlr jar file, and a cmake directory with the cmake rules for bringing in code:

```
antlr4-generator.cmake.in
4411 Aug 22 22:24 Antlr4Package.md
272 Aug 22 22:24 antlr4-runtime.cmake.in
5191 Aug 22 22:24 ExternalAntlr4Cpp.cmake
4787 Aug 22 22:24 FindANTLR.cmake
6762 Aug 22 22:24 README.md
```

I have to compile the parser myself, it isn't built into the cmake, which seems stupid.
Here is the CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)

project("xbf")

list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake)

# compiler must be at least 17
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

# required if linking to static library
add_definitions(-DANTLR4CPP_STATIC)

# using /MD flag for antlr4_runtime (for Visual C++ compilers only)
set(ANTLR4_WITH_STATIC_CRT OFF)
# add external build for antlrcpp
include(ExternalAntlr4Cpp)

# add antrl4cpp artifacts to project environment
include_directories(${ANTLR4_INCLUDE_DIRS})

# set variable pointing to the antlr tool that supports C++
# this is not required if the jar file can be found under PATH environment
set(ANTLR_EXECUTABLE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/tools/antlr-4.10.1-complete.jar)
# add macros to generate ANTLR Cpp code from grammar
find_package(ANTLR REQUIRED)

# CMake commands copied by the CMake file for CImg

# To use PKG_CHECK_MODULES to find some optional packages
find_package(PkgConfig)


# CMake commands for this specific project start here

# to disable some warnings for CImg
if (NOT WIN32)
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-Wdeprecated -Wno-attributes" )
endif()

if (APPLE)
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-Wdeprecated -std=c++11" )
endif()

if (MSVC)
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "/EHsc /wd4127 /wd4311 /wd4312 /wd4512 /wd4571 /wd4640 /wd4706 /wd4710 /wd4800 /wd4804 /wd4820 /wd4996")
endif()


# Call macro to add lexer and grammar to your build dependencies.
antlr_target(xbf xbf.g4 VISITOR OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/)

# add our project source directories
include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}
                     ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/
  )
  

add_executable(xbf src/main.cpp src/xbfParser.cpp src/xbfLexer.cpp ${ANTLR_XBF_CXX_OUTPUTS})

# link required libraries
target_link_libraries(xbf antlr4_static ${SYSTEM_LIBS})
```

The questions are:

How can I build the antlr4 build into the make process? Currently I type the command by hand, which is not why anyone uses cmake:

```
antlr4 -Dlanguage=Cpp xbf.g4
```

I don't want the generated files in the same directory as the source code, but if I compile and generate them in a separate directory and change the rule in cmake to get them from that directory then I get the following compile error:

```
antlr4 -Dlanguage=Cpp xbf.g4 -o libs
make
```

Then this line in CMakeLists.txt fails because the file xbfLexer.interp seems to have to be in the same directory as the grammar file.

```
add_executable(xbf src/main.cpp libs/xbfParser.cpp libs/xbfLexer.cpp ${ANTLR_XBF_CXX_OUTPUTS})

make[2]: *** No rule to make target 'xbf.g4', needed by 'libs/xbfLexer.interp'.  Stop.
```

The original line in the demo did not manually put in the dependencies on the generated code at all, but it does not seem to work. There were link errors for all the code referenced:

```
add_executable(xbf src/main.cpp ${ANTLR_XBF_CXX_OUTPUTS})
```

Is there a standard way to automatically set the variable ANTLR_XBF_CXX_OUTPUTS to refer to all the code generated so I don't have to manually put in all the files?